# Apache timeout instead of webpage

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables, timeout

instead of the desired webpages I get timeouts. If I try to get a page with wget on the server itself it works fine, but if I want to connect with a browser I get a timeout.

```
s15312615:/etc/apache2 # netstat -l
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdom:smtp *:*                     LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:www-http              *:*                     LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 *:snpp                  *:*                     LISTEN      
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8857   private/verify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8863   private/proxymap
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8866   private/smtp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8869   private/relay
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8875   private/error
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6037   @/var/run/hald/dbus-aXRNnAXQQw
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5897   /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8034   /var/run/mcelog-client
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8018   /var/run/nscd/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8019   /var/run/.nscd_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8878   private/discard
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8881   private/local
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8884   private/virtual
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8887   private/lmtp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5991   @/var/run/hald/dbus-98LA968QdN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8890   private/anvil
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8893   private/scache
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8896   private/maildrop
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8845   private/rewrite
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8899   private/cyrus
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8848   private/bounce
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8902   private/uucp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8851   private/defer
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8905   private/ifmail
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8854   private/trace
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8908   private/bsmtp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8911   private/procmail
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8914   private/retry
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8917   private/proxywrite
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8840   public/cleanup
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8860   public/flush
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8872   public/showq
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5964   /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
```

Output from iptables:

```
s15312615:/etc/apache2 # iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED 
input_ext  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
input_ext  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-IN-ILL-TARGET ' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            


Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-FWD-ILL-ROUTING ' 


Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-OUT-ERROR ' 

Chain forward_ext (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain input_ext (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = broadcast 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp source-quench 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request 
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp dpt:ssh flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP ' 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = multicast 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = broadcast 
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-    DROP-DEFLT ' 
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT ' 
LOG        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5     state NEW LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT ' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain reject_func (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with tcp-reset 
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
```

How can I solve this?

///EDIT
httpd.conf

```
### Global Environment ######################################################
#
# The directives in this section affect the overall operation of Apache,
# such as the number of concurrent requests.

# run under this user/group id
Include /etc/apache2/uid.conf

# - how many server processes to start (server pool regulation)
# - usage of KeepAlive
Include /etc/apache2/server-tuning.conf

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log

# generated from APACHE_MODULES in /etc/sysconfig/apache2
Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/loadmodule.conf

# IP addresses / ports to listen on
Include /etc/apache2/listen.conf

# predefined logging formats
Include /etc/apache2/mod_log_config.conf

# generated from global settings in /etc/sysconfig/apache2
Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/global.conf

# optional mod_status, mod_info
Include /etc/apache2/mod_status.conf
Include /etc/apache2/mod_info.conf

# optional cookie-based user tracking
# read the documentation before using it!!
Include /etc/apache2/mod_usertrack.conf

# configuration of server-generated directory listings
Include /etc/apache2/mod_autoindex-defaults.conf

# associate MIME types with filename extensions
TypesConfig /etc/apache2/mime.types
DefaultType text/plain
Include /etc/apache2/mod_mime-defaults.conf

# set up (customizable) error responses
Include /etc/apache2/errors.conf

# global (server-wide) SSL configuration, that is not specific to 
# any virtual host
Include /etc/apache2/ssl-global.conf

# forbid access to the entire filesystem by default
<Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

# use .htaccess files for overriding,
AccessFileName .htaccess
# and never show them
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# List of resources to look for when the client requests a directory
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.html.var

### 'Main' server configuration #############################################
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#
#Include /etc/apache2/default-server.conf


# Another way to include your own files
#
# The file below is generated from /etc/sysconfig/apache2,
# include arbitrary files as named in APACHE_CONF_INCLUDE_FILES and
# APACHE_CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS
Include /etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/include.conf

### Virtual server configuration ############################################
#
# VirtualHost: If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs-2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.
#
#Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/*.conf
Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/_vhost-master.conf


# Note: instead of adding your own configuration here, consider 
#       adding it in your own file (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf.local)
#       putting its name into APACHE_CONF_INCLUDE_FILES in 
#       /etc/sysconfig/apache2 -- this will make system updates 
#       easier :) 
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
AddType text/html .shtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

iptables -L -v

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   10  3008 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
13599  889K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED 
 2900  537K input_ext  all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 input_ext  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-IN-ILL-TARGET ' 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-FWD-ILL-ROUTING ' 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   10  3008 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere            
13313 5996K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-OUT-ERROR ' 

Chain forward_ext (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain input_ext (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
     1280  452K DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = broadcast 
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                icmp source-quench 
   10   461 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                icmp echo-request 
    7   392 LOG        tcp  --  any    any     anywhere                 anywhere                limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp dpt:ssh flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG     level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP ' 
        8   452 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = multicast 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            PKTTYPE = broadcast 
 1288 67240 LOG        tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT ' 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT ' 
    1   438 LOG        udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 state NEW LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix `SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT ' 
 1602 84345 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain reject_func (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with tcp-reset 
    0     0 REJECT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
```

///EDIT2

```
uname -a
Linux s15312615 2.6.34.8-0.2-default #1 SMP 2011-04-06 18:11:26 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If I try to open port 80 with

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp dport html -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp sport html -j ACCEPT
```

I get

```
Bad argument `dport'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

With

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

the command gets accepted but it changes nothing.

Comment: What's your Apache httpd.conf for your MPM?

Comment: added httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are allowing incoming connections on port 80 in your iptables settings, but it's hard to tell without seeing output from `iptables -L -v`.  Allow incoming port 80 to your firewall rules and it will likely work.

Comment: added iptables -L -v

How would I allow port 80?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the firewall was the problem.

In yast2 I went to -> Securtiy and Users -> Firewall -> Allowed Services and added http Server and voila it worked!